# it is not possible to display vector

Tags: c++, arrays, file, vector

This is my `txt` file where first line is number of `dataSets`. 2nd line(size1 variable) is equal to number of elements in 3rd line(A1 array) and 4th line(size2 variable) is equal to number of elements in 5th line(A2 array). My readFile function have to overwrite variables and arrays listed above without overwriting `dataSets` variable.

My `countElementsInArray` function is to count the number of occurrences of digits from the array `A2` in array `A1`. I have a problem when it comes to display vector named counts. I can see in debugger that elements returned from fcount function are passing to vector counts but it is not possible to output this vector(program stops there).

The idea of the program is to make vector array named counts where are number of occurrences of digits from the array `A2` in array `A1`.

txt:

```
3
4
-5 -1 0 8
7
7 9 2 0 -7 2 -5
4
1 2 3 4
2
1 1
5
0 0 0 0 0
1
3

Result for above input should be:
Dataset1:
0 0 0 1 0 0 1
Dataset2:
1 1
Dataset3:
0
```

```
int main() {

    std::fstream file;
    openFile(file);
    std::vector<int> v1,v2;
    fread(file, v1, v2);

    file.close();
    return 0;
}
void fread(std::fstream &file, std::vector<int> &A1, std::vector<int> &A2) {

    std::vector<int> counts;
    int dataSets, size1, size2, x, y;
    file >> dataSets;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dataSets; i++) {
        file >> size1;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < size1; j++) {
            file >> x;
            A1.push_back(x);
        }

        file >> size2;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            file >> y;
            A2.push_back(y);
        }

        for (size_t j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            int searchValue = A2[j];
            counts.push_back(fcount(A1, size1, searchValue));
        }

        int numberOfDataSet = i + 1;
        std::cout << "Dataset" << numberOfDataSet << ":" << std::endl;
        for(auto& k : counts)
            std::cout << k;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}


int fcount(std::vector<int> &A, int size, int searchValue) {

    int count = 0, first = 0, last = size;
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;
    while (first <= last) {
        int mid = first + (last - 1) / 2;

        if (A[mid] == searchValue) {
            count++;
            do {
                if (A[mid + i] == searchValue && A[mid - j] == searchValue) {
                    count += 2;
                    i++;
                    j++;
                } else if (A[mid + i] == searchValue) {
                    count++;
                    i++;
                } else if (A[mid - j] == searchValue) {
                    count++;
                    j++;
                }

                return count;
            } while (A[mid + i] == searchValue || A[mid - j] == searchValue);
        } else if (searchValue < A[mid])
            last = mid - 1;

        else if (searchValue > A[mid])
            first = mid + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: FYI, `std::set<int>` instead of `std::vector<int>`, and `std::set_intersection` instead of all of that code you have now makes this program trivial.

Comment: @John "I have a problem when it comes to display vector named counts. I can see in debugger that elements returned from fcount function are passing to vector counts but it is not possible to output this vector(program stops there)."
As i said, counts vector have a good values! The problem i have is connected with outputting the value from the vector.

Comment: The reason for the comment section is for comments, not answers.  I commented that the code could be easier.

Comment: Your vector `counts` should be declared inside the for loop as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not in displaying vector. Actual problem is in fcount function. It is trying to index vector with negative index value. So the program actually crashes. I made some changes to fix the issue

```
    int fcount(std::vector<int>& A, int size, int searchValue) {

int count = 0, first = 0, last = size - 1;
int i = 1;
int j = 1;
while (first <= last) {
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;  // Changed

    if (A[mid] == searchValue) {
        count++;
        do {
            if (A[mid + i] == searchValue && A[mid - j] == searchValue) {
                count += 2;
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else if (A[mid + i] == searchValue) {
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            else if (mid > j && A[mid - j] == searchValue) { // Changed
                count++;
                j++;
            }

            return count;
        } while (A[mid + i] == searchValue || A[mid - j] == searchValue);
    }
    else if (searchValue < A[mid])
        last = mid - 1;

    else if (searchValue > A[mid])
        first = mid + 1;
}
return count;
```

}

```
    void fread(std::fstream& file, std::vector<int>& A1, std::vector<int>& A2) {

std::vector<int> counts;
int dataSets = 0;
int size1 = 0;
int size2 = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
file >> dataSets;
for (size_t i = 0; i < dataSets; i++) {
    file >> size1;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < size1; j++) {
        file >> x;
        A1.push_back(x);
    }

    file >> size2;

    for (size_t j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
        file >> y;
        A2.push_back(y);
    }

    for (size_t j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
        int searchValue = A2[j];
        counts.push_back(fcount(A1, size1, searchValue)); // In second iteration this line cause crash. So count vector is not displayed
    }

    int numberOfDataSet = i + 1;
    std::cout << "Dataset" << numberOfDataSet << ":" << std::endl;
    for (auto& k : counts)
        std::cout << k;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

}

```
    int main() {

std::fstream file;
openFile(file);
std::vector<int> v1, v2;
fread(file, v1, v2);

file.close();
return 0;
```

}